# Haystack change SearchQuerySet of SearchForm

Tags: python, django, search, django-haystack

i want to customize the SearchQuerySet of a Search Form for search for all the possible results, like the sql expression "LIKE", the documentation says:

> SearchForm
>   The most basic of the form types, this form consists of a single field, the q field (for query). Upon searching, the form will take the cleaned contents of the q field and perform an auto_query on either the custom SearchQuerySet you provide or off a default SearchQuerySet.
>
> To customize the SearchQuerySet the form will use, pass it a searchqueryset parameter to the constructor with the SearchQuerySet you’d like to use. If using this form in conjunction with a SearchView, the form will receive whatever SearchQuerySet you provide to the view with no additional work needed.

It's possible to change auto_query to a icontains search?

That's my class, where i have to modify?:

```
class ContactSearchForm(HighlightedModelSearchForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=100,required=False)
    surname = forms.CharField(max_length=100,required=False)
    work = forms.CharField(max_length=100,required=False)
    province =  forms.CharField(max_length=100,required=False)
    status = forms.CharField(max_length=100,required=False)
    sex =  forms.CharField(max_length=100,required=False)
    city =  forms.CharField(max_length=100,required=False)
    street =  forms.CharField(max_length=100,required=False)
    zip =  forms.CharField(max_length=100,required=False)


    def no_query_found(self):
        return self.searchqueryset

    def search(self):
        sqs = super(ContactSearchForm,self).search()

        if not self.is_valid():
            return self.no_query_found()

        if self.cleaned_data['name']:
            sqs = sqs.filter(content__icontains = self.cleaned_data["name"])
        if self.cleaned_data['surname']:
            sqs = sqs.filter(content__icontains = self.cleaned_data['surname'])
        if self.cleaned_data['work']:
            sqs = sqs.filter(content__icontains = self.cleaned_data['work'])
        if self.cleaned_data['province']:
             sqs = sqs.filter(content__icontains = self.cleaned_data['province'])
        if self.cleaned_data['status']:
             sqs = sqs.filter(content__icontains = self.cleaned_data['status'])
        if self.cleaned_data['sex']:
             sqs = sqs.filter(content__icontains = self.cleaned_data['sex'])
        if self.cleaned_data['city']:
            sqs = sqs.filter(content__icontains = self.cleaned_data['city'])
        if self.cleaned_data['street']:
            sqs = sqs.filter(content__icontains = self.cleaned_data['street'])
        if self.cleaned_data['zip']:
            sqs = sqs.filter(content__icontains = self.cleaned_data['zip'])

        return sqs
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are invoking parent class search method which already executes auto_query. You don't need to do this:

```
sqs = super(ContactSearchForm,self).search()
```

Instead this should be your search method:

```
def search(self):
    if not self.is_valid():
        return self.no_query_found()

    sqs = self.searchqueryset
    for key, value in self.cleaned_data.items():
        if value:
            sqs = sqs.filter(content__icontains=value)

    if self.load_all:
        sqs = sqs.load_all()

    return sqs
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried this code and it's ok, but when i try to search "Rossi" for surname, he returns only the surname with "Rossi" and not the surname with "Rossini" for exmaple, why?

EDIT: when i type "R" in the search form he returns null...

Comment: The regular text field is probably not indexed to return partial matches. From what I know of Haystack's default behaviour, only the `autocomplete` fields (and the searches using them) return partial matches. For example, with a SOLR backend they use EdgeNgramFields that index 'Rossini' into tokens like 'R', 'Ro', 'Ros' etc. While the regular text field would only contain the token 'Rossini'.